# Jquery declaration issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, header, declaration

Recently, my jQuery code using events stopped working. I don't understand why. Do I have a declaration issue?

This is my declaration in the header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="description" content="">

    <meta name="author" content=XXXXXXX">
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/Bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/justified-nav.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Content/msdropdown/dd.css" />
    <link href="/Content/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/Content/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/Bootstrap-table.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/ManageSeason.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/site.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/sidebar_menu.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/js/msdropdown/jquery.dd.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>XXXXXX</title>

</head>
```

And my jQuery code:

```
 $('select[class*="selectEqRaceId"]').change(function () {
     // do some stuff
 });
```

and

```
$('#menu li a').click(
    function () {
        // Do some stuff
    }
);
```

It doesn't work. I click on the button or change the value of the select option.
The browser compilator doesn't go inside this event function.

Comment: 1) Why are you including the full version AND the minified version of jQuery?  2) Are you sure your functions are in the `document.ready()` function?

Comment: Ok, as i understand with all your responses, all functions using an event have to be in the document.ready(). I can have only 1 document.ready() so i need to use the document.ready in the main page? Right?

Comment: You have one `document.ready()` per page.  And yes, all your jQuery functions need to be in that function.

Comment: I have edited my answer, take a look at it.

Comment: It's works!! Thanks!!

Comment: I guess you dont really need two different versions of font-awesome either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import jQuery just once, use [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) function and take a look at the example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[class*="selectEqRaceId"]').change(function() {
    console.log("Changed via slect menu");
  });

  $('button').click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked via button");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select class="selectEqRaceId">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br>
<button>
  Click me
</button>
```

**EDIT:** 
You have to place the tags before the events get set or use the $(document).ready() function which will execute the code thats in it after the page finishes loading. It is always a good idea to use the $(document).ready() function.

I have added an example: 
1) Script after the tags without $(document).ready() 
2) Script before the tags without $(document).ready() (this wont work) 
3) Script before the tags WITH $(document).ready() function

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<h3>Script after the tags without $(document).ready()</h3>
<select class="afterTheTagsWithReady">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br>
<button class="afterTheTagsWithReady">Click me</button>
<script>
  // Without the $(document).ready() function and after the tags 
  $('select.afterTheTagsWithReady').change(function() {
    console.log("Changed via slect menu afterTheTagsWithReady");
  });

  $('button.afterTheTagsWithReady').click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked via button afterTheTagsWithReady");
  });
</script>



<h3>Script before the tags without $(document).ready() (this wont work)</h3>
<script>
  // Without the $(document).ready() function and after the tags 
  $('select.beforeTheTags').change(function() {
    console.log("Changed via slect menu beforeTheTags");
  });

  $('button.beforeTheTags').click(function() {
    console.log("Clicked via button beforeTheTags");
  });
</script>
<select class="beforeTheTags">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br>
<button class="beforeTheTags">Click me</button>



<h3>Script before the tags WITH $(document).ready() function</h3>
<script>
  // With the $(document).ready() function and before the tags 
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('select.beforeTheTagsWithReady').change(function() {
      console.log("Changed via slect menu beforeTheTagsWithReady");
    });

    $('button.beforeTheTagsWithReady').click(function() {
      console.log("Clicked via button beforeTheTagsWithReady");
    });
  });
</script>
<select class="beforeTheTagsWithReady">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<br>
<button class="beforeTheTagsWithReady">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Ok, as i understand with all your responses, all functions using an event have to be in the document.ready(). I can have only 1 document.ready() so i need to use the document.ready in the main page? Right?

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. Since you are loading all of your scripts in the head element, the script is executing correctly. It is attaching the event handler to all elements it finds at the time of script loading (which is none since the DOM tree of the body isn't constructed yet).

You have to wait for the elements to be loaded into the DOM tree before being able to manipulate them so you can fix this by loading your JS code just before the end of the closing body tag (i.e. inside the body after the other elements), or you can use the JQuery helper `$().ready(function)` so that it waits for the DOM tree to fully load before attempting to attach event handlers to elements.

```
$().ready(function(){
    $('#menu li a').click(function () {
        //Do some stuff
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, as i understand with all your responses, all functions using an event have to be in the document.ready(). I can have only 1 document.ready() so i need to use the document.ready in the main page? Right?

Comment: you can place $().ready anywhere. wherever it is loaded it will wait for the DOM tree construction to finish.